# Log data of http status 200 in user directory with Apache2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, http-status-code, 400

I want to log http status 200 data in my user directory with Apache2.4.

the current

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "~data” ssl_datalog nolog
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_data_log combined env= ssl_datalog
```

As, the directory can be restricted, but please tell me how to filter by http status.

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_data_log combined env=ssl_datalog "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} <= 210"
```

but got an error.

thanx